# Having trouble triggering the function FB.api() in the Facebook JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

The code below successfully triggers the FB.api() function when the button named "button2" is clicked however I am unable to trigger it from the button named "button1" event though I have verified that the button is triggering it's click handler. If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate it.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {      
          FB.init({ appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
            status: true, 
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true
                  });

         function updateButton(response) {
           var button1 = document.getElementById('subbtn');;
           var button2 = document.getElementById('fb-auth');

           button1.onclick = function(response){
             alert("Button1 Clicked");
             FB.api('/me', function(response) {
               alert("FB.api Triggered");
                                           });
                                                };

           if (response.authResponse) {
             //user is already logged in and connected
             var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
             FB.api('/me', function(response) {
               userInfo.innerHTML = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture">' + response.name;
               button2.innerHTML = 'Logout';
                                               });                             
              button2.onclick = function() {
                FB.logout(function(response) {
                  var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
                  userInfo.innerHTML="";
                                           });
                                            };
                                        } else {
              //user is not connected to your app or logged out
              button2.innerHTML = 'Login';
              button2.onclick = function() {
                FB.login(function(response) {
              if (response.authResponse) {
                    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                      alert("FB.api triggered");
                  var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
                  userInfo.innerHTML = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'  + response.id + '/picture" style="margin-right:5px"/>' + response.name;
                                                   });     
                                         } else {
                      //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
                                                     }
                                              }, {scope:'email'});      
                                              }
                                                 }
                                                 }

           // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
           FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
           FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);   
                                            };

           (function() {
             var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
             e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
             document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
                         }());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the difference between the two onclicks is that you are calling FB.login before you call FB.api in the button2 click event, but not in the button1 event:

```
button1.onclick = function(response){
             alert("Button1 Clicked");
             FB.api('/me', function(response) {
```

vs

```
button2.onclick = function() {
                FB.login(function(response) {
              if (response.authResponse) {
                    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
```

I'm guessing if you click button2 and then button1, that button1's handler works?